# Webpart dropdown menu appearing elsewhere

Tags: visual-web-part, internet-explorer, dropdown

[image: error in webpart dropdown]

As shown in the picture the dropdown menu is appearing elsewhere instead of appearing below the drop down arrow.This happens only when using in IE..
IE 8-11 all have this same issue. How can i solve this and make it appear normally.

EDIT:The site works fine in IE in the local system and doesn't show this issue , It happens only in the development server .

Comment: It seems you are using some styles which has conflict with SharePoint & IE. Try removing custom css and see if you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: The styles work fine in IE in the local system ... issue happens only in the development server.

Comment: That means there is some specific customizations installed on DEV.

Comment: The same wsp from the local is deployed into the dev. 
can you tell me What all customizations can affect this style?

Comment: Custom master page, page layouts, styles embedded inside the page.

Comment: the same custom master page, page layouts, styles used in local is deployed in dev. I have reached a dead end trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to troubleshoot something like this, remember that F12 is your friend. The CSS tab of most browser debuggers - IE, Chrome, Firefox - will allow you to select an element on the screen and see all CSS affecting it. In the case you describe, the menu element or one of its parent containers is being overridden by a style from one of the following locations:

- Master Page
- Primary Stylesheet (the one seen on ~siteURL/_layouts/changesitemasterpage.aspx)
- Alternate Stylesheet (usually loaded either through your primary stylesheet or a secondary one loading in the master page and/or the page* itself)
- Inline styles that located within the code of the page itself*
- Injected styles that are being inserted into the page via JavaScript or jQuery scripts

From the screenshot, you're most likely looking for a position style or float attribute. The IE debugger will allow you to uncheck styles to see how the page looks without them. It will also show you where the individual styles are coming from. When you uncheck a position or float and the menu jumps back to where it should be, you've found your culprit.

*Note: Remember that the page's code is a combination of Page Layout and actual page content. You'll need to check both places when eliminating anything inline.*

Comment: thank you for the reply.i had checked and found that the webpart menu is using different javscripts in local and DEV. But from where can i find this javscript code for webpart menu?. I checked in my custom master and corev4 and couldnt find it.

Comment: I take it the script is injecting some styling into the page? With IE, IIRC from the CSS tab you can click the script name on the right (beside the individual style causing the problem) and it will show you where the script is located at.

Comment: The same js function is called for the styling... but somehow its rendering differently...

Answer (score 0):

It is worth checking if IE is running in Standards mode in one environment and in compatibility mode in the other. This can be set by a group policy based on the site's URL.

Click F12 to bring up the developer tools and make sure that both of them are set to the same emulation. The interface is different depending on the version of IE, but for example:

[image]

EDIT: 
You have not provided sufficient information and i am trying to guess here. I suppose the 'local system' shows up in standards mode and the development server shows up in compatibility mode.

If this is the case, then probably you have a group policy for IE, which sets the internet options automatically for the users. Either checks the URL and sets IE in compatibility mode, or has the option to show all intranets in compatibility mode.

In this case, you will need to change this group policy. I am guessing this is about an intranet site.

Comment: I had set the document mode as ie8 in the code. the page works properly if the user agent string is also set as IE8. but changing that is not possible right??

Comment: You can change that for sure. It is either an organization group policy, or you will find the compatibility settings in Internet Explorer options. Search a bit and you will find them

Comment: I meant changing the user agent string as ie10 from the server itself.  changing this setting in clients browser is not an option